# Logstash - Read compressed strings from source

Tags: compression, logstash, influxdb

I have logstash setup which reads from Redis lists. Currently the data in those lists are bare strings, is there a way logstash can use compressed strings, uncompress them and then process the same?

Logstash forwarder (lumberjack) is not useful for me, In my case I have to use Redis as an in-between.

The current architecture looks something like this:

.Net app --> Redis List --> Logstash --> influx db

I want to:

.Net app --> compress string --> redis list --> logstash --> decompress --> influx db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you can code it in ruby, it can be done in logstash (via a custom filter or using a ruby code filter).  Without further information, that's the best answer that can be given.

Comment: What kind of information are you looking for? I want to store gzip or lz4 or any other compression algo compressed string in redis, I need logstash to decompress that string (maybe in a filter) and then pass it out to output. I wanted to stay away from writing a Ruby plugin (not a Ruby dev), although that can be my final option.

Comment: So, I found nothing, building a plugin for the same now.